# Cannot load images with pixi.js

Tags: typescript, sprite-sheet, pixi.js

I wanted to create a small game in **Typescript** using **Pixi.js** as a rendering engine. At the beginning I was following http://ezelia.com/2013/05/pixi-tutorial/. There were some mistakes in code but I managed to fix them. Now I wanted to load my spritesheet with pixi. Unfortunately I've got an error in the debug console: `Uncaught Error: The frameId 'body.png' does not exist in the texture cache function (baseTexture, frame)`.

That's my code to load the spritesheet:

```
var assetsToLoader = ["/pixi/img/Spritesheet.json"],
    loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader(assetsToLoader);
loader.onComplete = IntroScene.onAssetsLoaded;
loader.load();
```

Here is mine `IntroScene.onAssetsLoaded()` method:

```
private static onAssetsLoaded() {
    for (var i = 0; i < IntroScene.images.length; i++) {
        var frameName = IntroScene.images[i],
            texture = PIXI.Texture.fromFrame(frameName);
        IntroScene.textures.push(texture);
    }
}
```

That's my `IntroScene.images`:

```
private static images: any = [
    "body.png",
    "curvedBody1.png",
    "curvedBody2.png",
    "head.png",
    "tail.png",
    "smallFood.png",
    "bigFood.png",
    "background.png"
];
```

And finally `Spritesheet.json` generated with texture packer (http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker):

```
{"frames": [

{
    "filename": "background.png",
    "frame": {"x":2,"y":2,"w":64,"h":64},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":64,"h":64},
    "sourceSize": {"w":64,"h":64}
},
{
    "filename": "bigFood.png",
    "frame": {"x":68,"y":2,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "body.png",
    "frame": {"x":2,"y":68,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "curvedBody1.png",
    "frame": {"x":44,"y":68,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "curvedBody2.png",
    "frame": {"x":86,"y":68,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "head.png",
    "frame": {"x":2,"y":110,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "smallFood.png",
    "frame": {"x":44,"y":110,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
},
{
    "filename": "tail.png",
    "frame": {"x":86,"y":110,"w":40,"h":40},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
    "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
}],
"meta": {
    "app": "http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "image": "Spritesheet.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":128,"h":256},
    "scale": "1",
    "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:a9757ea06ba8b63665a1e5d45be72609$"
}
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone managed to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at example of spritesheet [here](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/blob/master/examples/example%203%20-%20MovieClip/SpriteSheet.json), as you see in example "frames" is a object, and you have array instead. Fix your **Spritesheet.json** or you can access to your textures by numerical id, for example PIXI.Texture.fromFrame(0) for body, PIXI.Texture.fromFrame(1) for curvedBody1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error doing the tutorial at
http://peepsquest.com/tutorials/isometric-tiles-with-height.html

I fixed this by replacing

> var tile = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame(filename);

with

> var tile = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(filename);

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to invoke `Texture.fromFrame` as if it's a static method, but it's actually an instance method. You probably meant to call `Texture.fromImage` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I thought `Texture.fromFrame` is a static method, but the docs are confirming your words. I will try to fix my code tomorrow and write how the things are going.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to make this work, so finally I decided to load separated images which is easy to implement.